# Unique solution to system of equations

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $|f'(x)|\leq 1/2$ for all $x$. Let $x_0,y_0$ be points in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the system \begin{cases} x+f(y)=x_0 \\ y+f(x)=y_0 \end{cases} has a unique solution.

My attempt: The system of equations implies $x=x_0-f(y)$ which implies $y=y-f(x)=y-f(x_0-f(y))$. So if we can show the map $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $h(y)=y-f(x_0-f(y))$ is a contraction, it will have a unique fixed point by Banach Contraction Theorem. However, I'm getting,

\begin{align}
|h(x)-h(y)|&=|[x-f(x_0-f(x))]-[y-f(x_0-f(y))]|\\
&=|x-y+f(x_0-f(y))-f(x_0-f(x))|\\
&\leq |x-y|+|f(x_0-f(y))+f(x_0-f(x))|\\
&\leq |x-y|+\frac{1}{2}|(x_0-f(y))-(x_0-f(x))|\\
&=|x-y|+\frac{1}{2}|f(x)-f(y)|\\
&\leq |x-y|+\frac{1}{4}|x-y|
\end{align}

Does anyone see how I can improve this bound or have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(x)=y_0-f(x)$ and $h(y)=x_0-f(y)$. Then you want a fixed point of 
$$F(x,y)=(h(y),g(x))$$

Now show there is an $0<\alpha<1$ such that $$\|F(x_1,y_1)-F(x_2,y_2)\|<\alpha \|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\|$$ for all $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$.

Comment: should it be $g(x)=y_0-f(x)$ and $h(y)=x_0-f(y)$?

Comment: Yep, need to fix. @user124910